# How to unsubscribe from a thread?

Tags: discussion

How can stop receiving notifications on a thread that I started and it's now resolved?

Comment: Should be on Meta. Include the post ID. But in any case, I don't know if there actually is a way to stop getting notifications on your own post - by definition any activity on it may be of interest to you, whether answer or comment or edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (I tend to avoid allowing notifications in the first place, so I'm unsure) you click on your avatar and score in the top bar, which brings up your activity, then go down below the badges, questions answers sections to where it says "following" and you should be able to unfollow from there. Or it may me that you just find the question/post/thread and uncheck  the "email me new responses" at the bottom, depending why you are getting notifications.

Additional option might be under settings/email settings on your profile. Reached by "edit profile" in the upper right of the same page mentioned at first here.

Comment: Worth noting that you cannot unfollow your own posts.

Answer (score 4):

### Try marking a "Best Answer"

This is a feature where the original asker can put a checkmark on the answer they like the most.  That *tells the system* that the question is resolved, and it does a couple of things.  First, it *tells other people* that your question is resolved, since not all of us are mind-readers, which deters additional answers.   Second, periodically StackExchange bumps some old questions to the top of the questions list, which of course causes them to get new answers **and this drives *us all* crazy as well**, by the way. IIRC choosing a "best answer" solves this. So be a bro.

I'm sure the emails mentioned this, as did a comment left when you asked.

As far as email settings, I got a ton of those when I started.  I dislike emails. I tried actually reading the email, and astonishingly, there was a link to manage email preferences!

Comment: ... and the instructions are at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)